# Are Google API's always at their respective URL's?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-api

I just started using googleapis.com where they host jquery codes for use.  I am using:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js
```

Now my question is if these codes are always there? or are they ever removed because i plan to use the source of the script as the one above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're always there, and you should consider using version 1.7.2 as of right now!

Millions of websites get the jQuery files from the Google API, so there's not a huge risk of them being removed any time soon, unless they are really outdated.

Comment: Yes, just change the version number in the link. There's no reason to download jQuery, some of the largest websites in the world use the Google API's for this, and there's no reason you should'nt aswell, and chances are that a user visiting your site already has the library cached, and that will improve the loading speed of your site for those users. I think version 1.2.something is still hosted by Google, so if using the newest version you'll probably be safe for the next 5-10 years, and by that time your site is outdated anyway.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know of any other jquery script that i can use where it queries the database to give options?

Comment: If you go to 1.5.1 and also go to 1.7.2 it looks slightly different, no?

Comment: They are different, but 1.7.2 is newest (at this moment) and has more functionality, plus it is more stable than the older version. One of key things why I would recommend using the newest version is plugin compatibility. Many of them are not compatible with older versions...
Hope this helps choosing the right version for your needs! Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are!

`Google` uses its `CDN (Content Delivery Network)` that helps you get libraries in fastest possible way by moving files to the servers nearest to you.

Besides being **very fast** it helps you to **stay updated** (in case of critical bug fixes) and also **saves bandwidth** for your website.

Comment: Can you elaborate on stay updated? Those files have their version locked, furthermore they have year long caches.

Comment: Normally they're not updated. But as centralized location (that gets distributed dynamicaly) it features capabilities to be updated in urgent cases.

Comment: Not with a year long cache it isn't. Google's analytics javascript on the other hand is more agile with a 12 hour cache so that they may push emergency updates to it.

Comment: You are completely right. It largely depends on a configuration of particular server.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the exactly same jQuery library source on a site for almost over a year now. It seems cool.

Of course Google can do what they want, so if you want to be sure download the file...

Comment: Yes i downloaded for one of the scripts i guess i will download this one too..   by the way do you know of any jquery scripts that use database query to display options in auto-suggest.  I have one but its limited to one field...Thanks!

Comment: Please try to find a related question or start a new question for this problem :)